# Unable to properly install binary edition of Apache Ant

Tags: java, windows-7, ant, installation

I'm following [this](http://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html) tutorial to install the binary edition of Apache Ant.

Unfortunately, when I get to the *"optional"* step 5, I'm unable to get some resources. That is, an error occurs while processing the Maven artifact tasks.

[image]

When I try to navigate to the servers, it appears that they are either down, or non-existent. Anyone else encounter this problem?

And I just found this piece of information regarding the [HTTP 403](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403) response code,

> This response is returned by the Apache web server when directory
>   listings have been disabled.

So, would enabling directory listings fix this? And if so, how do I go about enabling that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Ant is trying to download some JARs from a Maven repository on the Internet, in this case on JBoss' site. They changed the location of their repository some time ago.

Here's how to change the URL:

1. Go to your ant installation folder.
2. Open fetch.xml in your favorite text editor.
3. Search for http://repository.jboss.org/maven2 and replace it with https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty-releases/

Run the optional command again:

> ant -f fetch.xml -Ddest=system

Comment: Absolutely beautiful! Thank you so much, @JBert. I love this site..:D