# Unable to properly install binary edition of Apache Ant: jspc still not working

Tags: java, windows-7, ant, installation

I had the exact some problem as mentioned here:
[Unable to properly install binary edition of Apache Ant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7687383/unable-to-properly-install-binary-edition-of-apache-ant) .

I followed the steps by replacing http://repository.jboss.org/maven2 with https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty-releases/ but am still getting this error:

```
jspc:
[artifact:dependencies] Downloading: tomcat/jasper-compiler/4.1.36/jasper-compil
er-4.1.36.pom
[artifact:dependencies] [WARNING] Unable to get resource from repository remote
(http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/)
[artifact:dependencies] Downloading: tomcat/jasper-compiler/4.1.36/jasper-compil
er-4.1.36.pom
[artifact:dependencies] [WARNING] Unable to get resource from repository central
 (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
[artifact:dependencies] Downloading: tomcat/jasper-runtime/4.1.36/jasper-runtime
-4.1.36.pom
[artifact:dependencies] [WARNING] Unable to get resource from repository remote
(http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/)
[artifact:dependencies] Downloading: tomcat/jasper-runtime/4.1.36/jasper-runtime
-4.1.36.pom
[artifact:dependencies] [WARNING] Unable to get resource from repository central
 (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
```

This is the only module that doesn't install. Can one of you generous souls graciously help this lowly noob out? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those versions of of the jasper modules are missing POM files in Maven Central. That is why the download is failing:

- [jasper-compiler](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ctomcat%7Cjasper-compiler%7C4.1.36%7CN/A)
- [jasper-runtime](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ctomcat%7Cjasper-runtime%7C4.1.36%7CN/A)

Is it possible to use more recent versions?

---

## Update

The various libraries versions are controlled by the following file:

```
$ANT_HOME/lib/libraries.properties
```

Version 1.8.2 of ANT appears to be broken.I tried tweaking this file and finally gave up and upgraded to the latest version of ANT:

```
$ ant -version
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.3 compiled on February 26 2012

$ ant -f $ANT_HOME/fetch.xml -Ddest=user
```

I suggest an upgrade, or alternative take a copy of this version's properties file.

Comment: Thanks. How do I configure it to use more recent versions?

Comment: Ok, so I've upgraded to the latest version of Ant, but it still gives the same exact error message. 
ant -version gives 1.8.3 (as yours does above).
Thanks for the help!!!

Comment: Update: I've installed ant 1.8.3 and JDK 6 32-bit on another Windows 7 computer, but I get the exact same error message. Any ideas?

Comment: @osman You running from behind a corporate firewall? If so you may have to configure a HTTP proxy for your build: http://ant.apache.org/manual/proxy.html

Comment: Nope, not behind any firewalls. Tried turning off my firewall and got the same error.